Compactness topological subspaces
I'm a bit confused about the concept of compactness of a topological subspace.
Let's visualize the following situation: Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space, and let $W \subset X$ be a subset such that $\overline{W}$ is compact. We know that in this case $\overline{W}$ is a closed subset of $X$. Suppose $F \subset X$ is any closed subset. It's clear that $F\cap\overline{W}$ is also closed in $X$ and that $F\cap\overline{W}\subset\overline{W}$.
My question is: when considering $\overline{W}$ as a subspace of $X$, is $F\cap\overline{W}$ also compact, since it's a closed subset of a compact topological space $\overline{W}$? But is the compactness of $F\cap\overline{W}$ in relation to the topology of the whole space $X$ or in relation to the relative topology of the subspace $\overline{W}$?
Or better yet: is the compactness of a subset in the topology of the entire space inherited in the relative topology of a subspace?
Thanks for your help.

Note that the topology induced from $X$ and the topology induced from $\overline{W}$ are the same topology on $F\cap\overline{W}$. So it doesn't matter where you induce the topology from, you will get the same topological space. (and compactness depends only on the topology, so the space will be compact in either case)

Is this the general case? Is there any possibility of this not occurring?

What not occurring? If $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$ then $X$ and $B$ always induce the same topology on $A$. (assuming that $B$ has the induced topology from $X$) If you didn't see it before, just check using the definitions.

@Mark  Yes!  Joel should prove this using the definitions.

Thank you for your help!

I just have another question: To prove that two topologies $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are equal, is it sufficient to prove this in terms of set equality?

@JoelMarques You need to show both topologies have the same open sets. So yes, that means showing that $\tau=\tau'$ as sets.

Thank you very much!

You should separate out in your mind which properties of a space are topological - i.e., determined only by the topology of the space itself (compact, connected, separation axioms, etc) and which are only defined relative to the topology of some larger space containing it (open, closed, etc). If a set is compact, then it is compact in every space of which it is a subspace. But every subspace is closed in its own toplogy, even when it is not closed in a larger topology. Most properties you learn about are topological, simply because few relative properties are useful.

@PaulSinclair thanks for the advice.
